# What is an elegant way to replace the marked text of a beautifulsoup tag with a child tag containing the same text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have these tags like below, in some cases containing other tags (spans in these case)

```html
<p id="p:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{218}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="font-weight:bold">Test1###yrdy</span></p>,
 <p id="p:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{220}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test2###qweqwe</p>,
 <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{22}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="color:red">Test3</span> ###qweqeqwe</p>,
 <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{17}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test4 ### sfsfsdfds</p>,
 <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{19}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test5### 121212</p>
```

I am trying to figure out a way to replace what comes after ### and the ### with a span contatining the replaced text
I am looking at the .replace_with() method but that will replace the tag entirely

using the above against .string is not going to work as my strings are

```
Test1###yrdy  
Test2###qweqwe  
None  
Test4 ### sfsfsdfds  
Test5### 121212
```

So line 3 will be missed.  I also tried changing .contents 
 for p in paragraphs:

```
print(p.contents)
for content in p.contents:
    if "###" in content:
        content=content.replace("###",'<span>'+'###'+'</span>')
print (p.contents)
```

The above did not have any effect on the tree

The desired result (the text will be enclosed in its own span with some styling):

```html
<p id="p:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{218}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="font-weight:bold">Test1<span>###yrdy</span></span></p>,
 <p id="p:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{220}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test2<span>###qweqwe</span></p>,
 <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{22}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="color:red">Test3</span> <span>###qweqeqwe</span></p>,
 <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{17}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test4 <span>### sfsfsdfds</span></p>,
 <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{19}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test5<span>### 121212</span></p>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and post there desired result?

Comment: done see the last snippet please  ###text turns into <span>###test</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txt = '''<p id="p:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{218}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="font-weight:bold">Test1###yrdy</span></p>,
 <p id="p:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{220}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test2###qweqwe</p>,
 <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{22}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="color:red">Test3</span> ###qweqeqwe</p>,
 <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{17}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test4 ### sfsfsdfds</p>,
 <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{19}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test5### 121212</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

r = re.compile(r'(.*?)(###.*)')

for tag in soup.find_all(lambda tag: any('###' in c for c in tag.contents)):
    # find content index:
    for idx, c in enumerate(tag.contents):
        if '###' in c:
            break
    tag.contents[idx] = BeautifulSoup(r.sub(r'\1<span>\2</span>', tag.contents[idx]), 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<p id="p:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{218}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="font-weight:bold">Test1<span>###yrdy</span></span></p>,
 <p id="p:{659babcd-9de3-0e7a-27ba-7fa0325a40f7}{220}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test2<span>###qweqwe</span></p>,
 <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{22}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="color:red">Test3</span> <span>###qweqeqwe</span></p>,
 <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{17}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test4 <span>### sfsfsdfds</span></p>,
 <p id="p:{d59b11dc-654f-0d5c-0ee2-f66181a6fa4b}{19}" lang="en-US" style="font-size:10.5pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Test5<span>### 121212</span></p>
```

Comment: alien code for me :-) ..tryimg to understand what this does BeautifulSoup(r.sub(r'\1<span>\2</span>', tag.contents[idx]). I have the tags as list (remember the other thread where you helped me) . This gives me an idea..try to do the replacements before "souping" the string. I do need to push back to the server the modified paragraphs

Comment: @MiniMe You can do regex: `print( re.sub(r'(###.*?)</p>', r'<span>\1</span></p>', txt) )`, where variable `txt` is the HTML string from your question. But beware of the corner cases.

Comment: Yes I figured that out from your reply
I am intrigued by the magic that happens in this line
tag.contents[idx] = BeautifulSoup(r.sub(r'\1<span>\2</span>', tag.contents[idx]), 'html.parser')   I get it that you found all the p and then scanned their content and found the string to be replaced but then you seem to be able to replace the relevant content with the soup created by this BeautifulSoup(r.sub(r'\1<span>\2</span>', tag.contents[idx]), 'html.parser') I think I tried something similar. If you change the contents of a tag will that reflect in the soup?

Comment: @MiniMe Yes, changing the `.contents` of the tag changes the soup, but you cannot just pass string `<span>...</span>` to the `.contents`, you have to first generate new tag (with `BeautifulSoup('<span>...</span>')` and then pass the result to `.contents`.